# print value of check box

Tags: jquery

i have 10 check box. I want to capture in array and print value as the user checked checkbox. if he uncheck, value should be unprinted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    var errorElements = [], valid = false;

 $('.checkboxgroup', this).each(function() {
        var checkBoxes = $(':checkbox', this), oneChecked = false;
        checkBoxes.each(function() {
            if ( !oneChecked && !$(this).is(':checked') ) {
                valid = false;
                errorElements.push(this);
            } else {
                oneChecked = true;
            }
        });
    });

  e.preventDefault(); // cancels form submit.. remove if you dont need.

  if ( errorElements.length ) {
     // code to do what you want if it fails
  } else {
     // code to do what you want if it passes
  }


});
```

html:

```
<div class="checkboxgroup">

( checkbox html )

</div>


<div class="checkboxgroup">

( checkbox html )

</div>
```